Unclear about the definition of "mutually exclusive"
Google says, "mutually exclusive is a statistical term describing two or more events that cannot happen simultaneously."
But when we say that $n$ events are mutually exclusive, we mean that nothing is in common between them, correct?
So, when we say that $n$ claims are mutually exclusive, are we actually saying that exactly 1 is true, or that at most 1 is true?

It means that if one of the claims is true, then all of the others must be false.  It is perfectly possible for all the claims to be false.

at most one is true.

But when we say "n mutually exclusive events", we mean to say nothing is in common between them, correct?

Not following.  With mutually exclusive events, we again have that, if one of them occurs, none of the others occur. So, again, at most one of the events might occur.

Sometimes one speaks of events which are both "mutually exclusive" and "exhaustive".  That means that exactly one of the events must occur.  If you select a natural number, for example, it must be even or odd, it can't be both.

Sorry I mean, as per google definition, "Mutually exclusive is a statistical term describing two or more events that cannot happen simultaneously"... so if 2 or more things can't occur simultaneously, then that means  $\geq 2$ events can't be "true" (or occuring) at same time, hence it's "at most 1 event" is occuring/true?

@lulu Oh ok I see. So "mutually exclusive" means "$\leq1$ event occurs/is true" and "exhaustive" means "$\geq1$ event occurs/is true"?

That's right. $\quad$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

With reference to three or more events, there are actually two conflicting definitions of mutually exclusive. Consider the mutually exclusive events $A, B$ and $C.$

Google says, "mutually exclusive is a statistical term describing two or more events that cannot happen simultaneously."

By this definition (collectionwise mutual exclusivity), no outcome belongs to all of the three events, that is, $$A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset.\tag1$$

But when we say that $n$ events are mutually exclusive, we mean that nothing is in common between them, correct?

By this definition (pairwise mutual exclusivity), no pair of events can simultaneously happen, that is, $$A\cap B=B\cap C=A\cap C=\emptyset.\tag2$$

So, when we say that $n$ claims are mutually exclusive, are we actually saying that exactly 1 is true, or that at most 1 is true?

$\text“n$ claims are mutually exclusive”, by the first definition:

at least one claim is false.

$\text“n$ claims are mutually exclusive”, by the second definition ✔️:

at most one claim is true.

$\text“n$ claims are collectively exhaustive”:

at least one claim is true.

$\text“n$ claims are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive”, by the second definition ✔️:

exactly one claim is true.

